# How to query oracle table with json column as table and aggregate values

Tags: oracle

I have a data table in oracle database with one json blob column. The data is as following json structure.

```
{
  "type_a": [
    {
      "line_item_a": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      },
      "line_item_b": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      },
      "line_item_c": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      },
      "line_item_d": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "type_b": [
    {
      "line_item_a": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      },
      "line_item_b": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      },
      "line_item_c": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      },
      "line_item_d": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "type_c": [
    {
      "line_item_a": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      },
      "line_item_b": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      },
      "line_item_c": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      },
      "line_item_d": {
        "cost": 1284,
        "discount": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "customerId": "8E7A44BA8CE6BF76D09497246C5246FB",
  "priceType": {
    "id": 1,
    "selected": false,
    "text": "Corporate"
  }
}
```

I am trying to read values in this column with following following structure;

| line_item_a | line_item_b | line_item_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cost(type_a) + cost(type_b) + cost(type_c) | cost(type_a) + cost(type_b) + cost(type_c) | cost(type_a) + cost(type_b) + cost(type_c) |

Can you please help me formulate a query for this?

Comment: The formula is the same for all the columns. Is this a typo? Do you need to have fixed output (a, b and c despite the presence of d, for eample)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not a graceful solution, but here's a very basic way to do that with JSON_TABLE.

Assuming your table is named MY_TABLE with json blob col JSON_COL.

```
select jt.customer_id, 
    (li_a_type_a + li_a_type_b + li_a_type_c) as line_item_a,
    (li_b_type_a + li_b_type_b + li_b_type_c) as line_item_b,
    (li_c_type_a + li_c_type_b + li_c_type_c) as line_item_c 
from my_table t
cross join json_table(t.json_col, '$'
    COLUMNS (
        customer_id  varchar2(50 char) PATH '$.customerId',
        li_a_type_a number PATH '$.type_a.line_item_a.cost',
        li_b_type_a number PATH '$.type_a.line_item_b.cost',
        li_c_type_a number PATH '$.type_a.line_item_c.cost', 
        li_d_type_a number PATH '$.type_a.line_item_d.cost',
        li_a_type_b number PATH '$.type_b.line_item_a.cost',
        li_b_type_b number PATH '$.type_b.line_item_b.cost',
        li_c_type_b number PATH '$.type_b.line_item_c.cost', 
        li_d_type_b number PATH '$.type_b.line_item_d.cost',
        li_a_type_c number PATH '$.type_c.line_item_a.cost',
        li_b_type_c number PATH '$.type_c.line_item_b.cost',
        li_c_type_c number PATH '$.type_c.line_item_c.cost', 
        li_d_type_c number PATH '$.type_c.line_item_d.cost'  
        )) as jt
;
```

Comment: thanks @kfinity; this is good progress. what should I do, if the number of line item is not fixed?